# Getting Special Folder Path from OpenDialog selection in Delphi

Tags: delphi, path, special-folders, topendialog

I let my users select a folder via the OpenDialog component.

However, when they select a folder such as Documents or My Videos or something like that, the path is just the name of the folder.

I can get the path of such folder via the API, but how do I get the path
based on what they've selected in the OpenDialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are actually talking about a user selecting a Windows 7 library. In which case you need to use special code to find the default save location for that library.

You need to use the `IFileDialog` interface to do this. If you use `TOpenDialog` then you don't have access to the `IFileDialog` interface. So you need to use the Vista dialog, `TFileOpenDialog` which does expose the `IFileDialog` interface.

Once you have this interface you can obtain `IShellItem` interfaces for each selected shell item by calling `GetResults` for multi-select dialogs, and `GetResult` for single-select dialogs. You can then pass these `IShellItem` interfaces to a function like this:

```
function ShellItemFileSystemPath(const si: IShellItem): string;
var
  attribs: DWORD;
  pszPath: PChar;
  lib: IShellLibrary;
  defSaveFolder: IShellItem;
begin
  OleCheck(si.GetAttributes(SFGAO_FILESYSTEM, attribs));
  if attribs=0 then begin
    // This could be a library, in which case we shall return the default save location
    if  Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLibrary, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLibrary, lib))
    and Succeeded(lib.LoadLibraryFromItem(si, STGM_READ))
    and Succeeded(lib.GetDefaultSaveFolder(DSFT_DETECT, IShellItem, defSaveFolder)) then begin
      Result := ShellItemFileSystemPath(defSaveFolder);
      exit;
    end;
    raise EValidityError.CreateFmt(
      'Cannot operate on ''%s'' because it is not part of the file system.',
      [ShellItemDisplayName(si)]
    );
  end;
  OleCheck(si.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, pszPath));
  Try
    Result := pszPath;
  Finally
    CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);
  End;
end;
```

The code in the Embarcadero libraries should be doing this, but sadly that library code is deficient. It should be supporting Windows 7 libraries by now.

Personally, I don't use the Embarcadero provided file dialogs because of this issue and others.

Comment: Probably commctrl but you won't have IFileDialog if your delphi is old. You'd have to define it yourself.